# Передача данных поля в метод контроллера

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Интересует вопрос: Как из полей View типа Input при вводе в Runtime приложения передать данные в метод контроллера без использования БД. Например в форме 2 Input поля и button с lable, который объеденяет два inputa после клика. Спасибо.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Приведите пример того, что вы сделать хотите. Конкретно не ясно при чем тут БД

Comment: tym32167 Есть MVC паттерн на ASP.NET, нужно из полей input на View передать в метод контроллера. Как это сделать? Читаю про методы HttpPost, но не знаю как проинициализировать поля на View, что бы передать в контроллер.

Comment: причём тут runtime и БД?

Comment: `<input name="myField" id="myField" />` и в контроллере `Result MyAction(srting myField)`

Comment: @Rifter, правильно ли я Вас понял, что Вам надо во время работы Вашего приложения получать значения input-элементов формы в контроллере?

Comment: @Serafim Prozorov да, из View в инпут поле нужно передавать данные в контроллер. Я наверное многих озадачил, написал про БД, до этого я обращался через ViewBag с Post запросом, из которых уже манипулировал данных, сейчас мне нужно обойти использование БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению не смог донести свою идею аудитории, но все же разобрался сам в данном вопросе. И так, передача данных из View в Controller происходит следующим образом:

Методы **[HttpGet]** и **[HttpPost]** - Get - принимает параметры, Post - отправляет.
Во вкладке View можно воспользоваться методом:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)){}
```

где, Index - Название метода и View формы, Home - Название контроллера (HomeController). Передача происходит обычными input боксами.

Возврат полученных Input -ов отражается в [HttpPost] методе с обычной сигнатурой с указанием полей из View. Пример:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Index(Mail mail)
    {
        return mail.Sender + mail.Password;
    }
```

Метод - Index, соответственно имя View - Index. Объект Mail - модель, с указанием параметров. Соответственно View должна быть:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><p>Enter your mail</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Sender" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>Enter your password</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Password"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Post"/></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Возвращаемый результат - Sender+Password.

Альтернативное использование метода Html.BeginForm - Создание Form поля на View:

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Index">
```

Более детально про взаимодействие компонентов в паттерне MVC, можете прочесть в этом источнике - https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/4.6.php